# @Html.ValidationMessageFor check empty or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, unobtrusive-validation

There is this code

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Email, null, new { @class = "test" })
        </div>
```

and it supposed to use `alert alert-danger` bootstrap classes for error messages. But in this case `alert alert-danger` div is visible any time even though there are not any validation errors.

[image]

Is there any way to check if error message appeared and show `alert alert-danger` div only in this case?

Comment: write a javascipt for null check,if it is null show this `div`,initially hide this `div`.

Answer (score 3):

Add classes to the `ValidationMessageFor` helper itself and not to the outed div:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Email, "Your message", new { @class = "test alert alert-danger" })
```

**UPDATE**

In addition to that you need to modify `.field-validation-valid` class which is added to valid input to hide it:

```
.field-validation-valid
{
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I know about this opportunity and I tried it but `alert alert-danger` div has some paddings anyway and even though it's empty it's visible http://i.imgur.com/Vk5MrhO.png

Comment: Are you using LESS for creating your css files?

Comment: No, I just uploaded `Bootstrap`using NuGet Packages (css and js files)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using unobtrusive validation then you'll need to use JavaScript to dynamically show and hide the wrapper `div` as the validation changes.

Here's a proof-of-concept that should hopefully be close to what you need. (Note that it relies on some implementation details of unobtrusive validation, so no guarantees that it'll work in all circumstances.)

```
<!-- i've added a new "valmsg-wrapper" class to your div -->
<div class="alert alert-danger valmsg-wrapper">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Email, null, new { @class = "test" })
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        // hide the wrapper div on load if there's no server-side validation message
        $('div.valmsg-wrapper').not(':has(span.field-validation-error)').hide();
    });

    // store the existing highlight/unhighlight functions before overriding them
    var original_highlight = $.validator.defaults.highlight;
    var original_unhighlight = $.validator.defaults.unhighlight;

    $.validator.setDefaults({
        highlight: function (elem, err, val) {
            // call the highlight function and then show the relevant wrapper div
            original_highlight(elem, err, val);
            $('div.valmsg-wrapper').has('span[data-valmsg-for="' + elem.name + '"]').show();
        },
        unhighlight: function (elem, err, val) {
            // call the unhighlight function and then hide the relevant wrapper div
            original_unhighlight(elem, err, val);
            $('div.valmsg-wrapper').has('span[data-valmsg-for="' + elem.name + '"]').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```